# How to get started developing for Internet.org (free basics)

Tags: facebook

Question about **internet.org** which is facebook's platform for the developing world.

I am a developer sitting in the US and I would like to develop a website for this service.

- How do I access this service in the US? Is it even possible?
- Can a developer based in the US realistically develop for this service or do I need to be on one of the preferred networks e.g. Reliance in India?

Answer (score -1):

There's a page on facebook named [internet.org - getting started for developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internet-org/gettingstarted)

Which include:

**Build Your App**

[Technical Guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internet-org/platform-technical-guidelines)
Build your service to be compatible with the Free Basics Platform.

[Participation Guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internet-org/participation-guidelines)
Comply with the Participation Guidelines.

[Test Your Service](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internet-org/platform-technical-guidelines#testing)
Ensure your service is mobile compatible by testing with a mobile emulator.

---

**Submit for Technical Review**

[Prepare your Submission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internet-org/review/how-to-submit)
Learn what to expect from the technical review process and read tips on preparing your submission.

[Showcase Examples](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internet-org/review/examples)
See examples of services optimized for the Free Basics Platform.

[Submit for Technical Review](http://internet.org/platform/submit)
Submit your service for Free Basics Platform technical review.

---

**Submission Feedback**

[Understand Your Submission Feedback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internet-org/review/feedback)
Understand your submission responses and read tips on fixing common issues.

Comment: My problem at this time is even more basic than that. How do I access this service?

Comment: You should read [Technical Review - how-to-submit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internet-org/review/how-to-submit)